# Do you need components for the necklace of prayer beads?

Tags: dnd-5e, spell-components

With a bit of luck one can find a necklace of prayer beads that has the greater restoration spell stored in it. That spell has an expensive component, namely 100 gp worth of diamond dust. Do you need this (or any other) component to cast the spell from the necklace?

Comment: Nice answer in less than 3 min thanks. Stupid rpg.se search didn't show the other post.